# Как получить из словаря список ключей?

Tags: delphi-xe

```
Var
  Dict: TDictionary<String, String>;
Begin
  Dict:=TDictionary<String, String>.Create;
  Dict.Add('Key1', 'Value1');
  Dict.Add('Key2', 'Value2');
  Dict.Add('Key3', 'Value3');
  Dict.Add('Key4', 'Value4');
  //..
End;
```

Нужно получить строку 'Key1, Key2, Key3, Key4'. Как это правильнее сделать? Создал TArray загнал ключи в него Dict.Keys.ToArray и оттуда выковырял значения в строку, но уж больно мне не нравится такой подход)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for Key in Dict.Keys do
  // что-то делаем с Key
```

Comment: а **Key** какого типа будет? У типа **Key: TDictionary<String, String>.TKeyCollection;** нет такого свойства

Comment: @Isaev А, AStringProperty это у TKeyClass. У вас Key типа String будет

Comment: спасибо, всё просто, как я и подозревал)

Comment: А можно их получить в том же порядке, в котором записывали? Он их все перемешал)

Comment: @Isaev Нет. Словари не поддерживают сортировку, порядок элементов случаен. Это же обычная хеш таблица.

Comment: Но если очень хочется изменить порядок, то можно, если при создании словаря `TDictionary` указать собственный созданный компаратор, реализующий интерфейс IEqualityComparer, и в котором реализован нужный вам способ сортировки. А в остальном @Suvitruf прав, не предназначены словари для хранения сортированных значений, это хэш таблица и обращение к элементам идет по ключу.